# Find all real numbers m for which equation $z^3+(3+i)z^2-3z-(m+i)=0$ has ..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem :

Find all real numbers m for which equation $z^3+(3+i)z^2-3z-(m+i)=0$ has atleast a real root.

No idea of approach :

I am not getting idea how to approach a cubic polynomial in complex numbers please provide some hint will be of great help thanks.

Comment: You have $z^3+3z^2-3z-m=i(z^2-1)$, so taking $z=\pm1$ gives you two possible values for $m$. Is it possible to get any others?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $z$ and $m$ are real

then $$z^3 + (3+i)z^2 -3z - (m+i) =0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow z^3+3z^2+iz^2-3z-m-i=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (z^3+3z^2-3z-m) + i(z^2-1) = 0 $$

$$ \Re = 0 ~~ \Im = 0 $$

Consider $\Im = 0$ first , hence

$$ z^2 = 1 $$

$$ z = \pm 1$$

Now with the Real part:

$$ \Re(z) = z^3+3z^2-3z-m $$

$$ \Re(1) = 1+3-3-m = 0 ~~ , ~ \Re(-1) = 5-m=0$$

$$ \therefore m = 1,5 $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What are the real and imaginary parts of the left-hand side?